# List подсчёт чисел c#

Tags: c#, list

У меня есть List (ниже код)

```
List<KeyLenght> lenght = new List<KeyLenght>(); //лист с ключами
            #region подсчёт
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 2, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 3, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 4, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 5, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 6, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 7, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 8, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 9, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 10, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 11, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 12, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 13, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 14, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 15, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 16, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 17, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 18, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 19, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 20, howMany = 0 });
            lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 21, howMany = 0 });
            #endregion
```

(после main есть ещё класс для этого листа)

```
public class KeyLenght
        {
            public int lenght;
            public int howMany;
        }
```

Я в цикле считаю числа, которые "работают" по определённой формуле. Далее, мне нужно найти число, которое чаще всего встречается.

Пытался реализовать вот так:

```
for (double l = 2; l <= 21; l++)
{
if ((j - i) > 0) //если число положительное (проверка)
    {
    double Check = (j - i) / l; //и выполняется условие
    if (Check % 1 == 0) //и остаток от деления равен 0
        {
            lenght[Convert.ToInt32(l)].howMany++; //ТО увеличить howMany на 1
        }
    }
}
```

Но почему-то это не работает - выдаёт ошибку:
*System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index"*

Comment: Вам не кажется, что остаток от деления на 1 всегда будет 0? "Если число положительное": `if(number % 2 == 0)`... j, i - откуда они? Чему равны? Вы бы проще описали то, что пытаетесь сделать...

Comment: пишется `Length`, не `Lenght`

Comment: Пытайтесь не дублировать код, вот если вы видите частое повторение строк или прям участков кода, то вы явно делаете что-то не так. К примеру, всю вашу портянку с `.Add()` можно заменить на `var lenght = Enumerable.Range(2, 20).Select(x => new KeyLenght() { lenght = x });`. Как видите, все ваши ~20 строк дублирующего кода (которые вы еще в регион засунули, чтоб глаза не мозолили) успешно заменились одной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, для ваших целей лучше подойдёт Dictionary, а во вторых...
Индексирование lenght[] имеет по индексу 0 объект:

```
lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 2, howMany = 0 });
```

А значит объект

```
lenght.Add(new KeyLenght() { lenght = 21, howMany = 0 });
```

будет расположен в списке по индексу 19, а вы пытаетесь обратится к нему по lenght[21].
Так что в конкретном случае делайте так:

```
lenght[Convert.ToInt32(l)-2].howMany++;
```

Правильным решением будет использовать словарь для этих целей, и класс KeyLenght будет не нужен:

```
Dictionary<int, int> KeyLength = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (double l = 2; l <= 21; l++)
{
    if ((j - i) > 0) //если число положительное (проверка)
    {
        double Check = (j - i) / l; //и выполняется условие
        if (Check % 1 == 0) //и остаток от деления равен 0
        {
            int l_int = Convert.ToInt32(l);
            if (KeyLength.ContainsKey(l_int)) KeyLength[l_int]++;
            else KeyLength[l_int] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить наиболее чаще встречающийся элемент:

```
if (dic.Count = 0) return -1; //элементов нет вообще
int maxval = dic.Max(m => m.Value); //наибольшее значение счётчика
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> listwithmaxvals = dic.Where(w => w.Value == maxval); //список записей с наибольшим значением счётчика
int[] maxvalkeys = listwithmaxvals.Select(s => s.Key).ToArray(); //массив ключей с наибольшим значением счётчика
int maxvalkey = listwithmaxvals.ElementAt(0).Key; //первый элемент с максимальным значением счётчика
int maxvalfirstval = dic[maxvalkey]; //значение первого элемента, смысла особо не имеет, т.к. есть int maxval
```